# Appendices and custom chapter headings not playing nice

Tags: appendices

Odd one here, can't get round it for the life of me: the custom chapter headings in my class file are being very odd when the `appendices` environment is enabled.  Mostly, the first one numbers fine, but the second is picking up whatever the last chapter count before the `appendices` environment was!  Outputting the counter doesn't do this, though - and the ToC entry is correct.

It appears just using `\appendix` works fine - but this has got me puzzled [and I'd rather have the extras of the environment than do them myself].

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,sabonnumbers]{thesis}

\usepackage[american]{babel} %not quite sure why this and the next are necessary, but wouldn't compile without
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, natbib, citestyle=authoryear, hyperref, sortcites=true, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\usepackage[toc,page,title,titletoc,header]{appendix}
\noappendicestocpagenum

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Contemporary Loyalist Paramilitary Organisations}\label{app:loyalist}
\thechapter

This seems fine.

\chapter{Contemporary Nationalist Paramilitary Organisations}\label{app:nationalist}
\thechapter

What the...?

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Class file [here](https://pastebin.com/qyjyBTdy) was not originally mine, though I've played around with it some - only thing I've done to the chapter numbers is moved them around.  This all worked fine for my own thesis, but that was back in 2013.